# Newlines entered in Firefox not dislplaying in SQR Report

Tags: peoplesoft, sqr

Let's say I have a text field here named "Description". In the Description field, I entered the following text:

This is line 1.
This is line 2.

This is line 3.

When I input these text to the Description field using IE or Chrome and run the SQR process, the description is displayed correctly including the newlines. But when I enter the same description using Firefox (v35.0.1 btw), the description is being printed in the report like this:

This is line 1. This is line 2. This is line 3.

I am sure that in my SQR there are no procedures that strip off the newlines (because it is working with IE and Chrome). I have also validated backend that the description has newlines.

Using the data entered in Firefox, I also tried running the report in IE and Chrome, but the newlines are still not displaying.

Can you tell me why is this happening? Is there a difference between the newlines used by IE, Chrome, and Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, google `firefox textarea newline`.

Firefox represents an newline as linefeed character `ascii(10)` whereas internet explorer as a combination of carriage return character and linefeed character `ascii(13)` `ascii(10)`.

To ensure the data is saved in the way it's required for your further processes, you could add component record peoplecode, SavePreChange:

```
/* Newline is Char13)+Char(10) */
YOUR_REC.YOUR_FLD.Value = Substitute(
                            Substitute(YOUR_REC.YOUR_FLD.Value, 
                                       Char(13) | Char(10), 
                                       Char(10)), 
                            Char(10), 
                            Char(13) | Char(10));
```